# How to extract username, password and database, or connection url in JBoss via Java code?

Tags: java, xml, jboss, jndi

Does anyone know how to extract username, password and database, or connection url in a JBoss/JNDI via Java code?
I need this to connect directly with the database, without use the connection pool, but taking advantage of the JNDI configuration.

This is my JNDI configuration:

```
<datasources>
  <local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>WonderDesenv</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.74:1521:DESENV</connection-url>
    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>

    <user-name>wonder</user-name>
    <password>wonder</password>

    <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>50</max-pool-size>

    <idle-timeout-minutes>10</idle-timeout-minutes>
    <prepared-statement-cache-size>30</prepared-statement-cache-size>

    <blocking-timeout-millis>30000</blocking-timeout-millis>

    <new-connection-sql>
    </new-connection-sql>

    <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1 from dual</check-valid-connection-sql>
    <track-statements>true</track-statements>
        <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>

    <metadata>
      <type-mapping>Oracle9i</type-mapping>
    </metadata>
  </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

Answer (score 2):

you havent specified what you were using like EJB or etc.... anyways,

you need to add this in your web.xml

```
 <resource-ref>
 <description>Oracle Datasource example</description>
 <res-ref-name>jdbc/WonderDesenv</res-ref-name>
 <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
 <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
 </resource-ref>
```

and a simple context lookup as

```
    Context initContext = new InitialContext();
    Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
    DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/WonderDesenv");
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
    ....
```

Comment: I have already put this is jboss-web.xml, except res-type and res-auth. But what I need is after get the connection, extract the URL, username and password...

Comment: I got confused.. why do you need this URL/pwd/usern name ?

Comment: Because I want to connect directly with database, without use the JBoss connection pool. I am deploying a JRubyOnRails application, using oracle_enhanced adapter, which is incompatible with jndi, so I need only to share the connection info

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to get the DataSource object via JNDI, then downcast it to the specific class that JBoss gives you. The exact class depends on the type of datasource you're creating.  (XA vs local) DataSource by iteself doesn't have references to the connection info.   If you post your -ds.xml file, it might be helpful.

Update:  I think I found your solution after a little searching.  It's much cleaner if you could just refer to the JNDI datasource.  This would be a much better solution than creating a connection yourself, since this would utilize the safety of using the jboss connection pool.

https://syntatic.wordpress.com/2008/08/20/connection-pooling-for-rails-on-jruby-using-jndi-and-jdbc/

Comment: Thank you a lot. I posted the JNDI source. If you can help me exactly how to extract I will appreciate.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, because I use a different adapter than jdbc, that is oracle_enhanced, which, even if I explicitly request it to release the connection it doesn't. So I want to connect directly.

Comment: That's true that when you close a connection in a pool, it doesn't really close it, it just puts it back in the pool.  But why do you need to explicitly release a connection?  In the past, when I've seen developers roll their own connection management, it usually ends badly.